# How to use NSFetchedResultsController and UISearchController together?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a view that contains a tableView. I'm using `NSFetchedResultsController` to display my results from Core Data.

I'd like to add a UISearchController (not a `UISearchDisplayController` as this one is deprecated in iOS 8) but I don't know how to link them.

Should I have only one `NSFetchedResultsController` or two?
I guess there is a way to fetch all the data with the `NSFetchedResultsController` and then just sort them according to the `UISearchController` am I wrong?

Thanks for the help you can give me on this.

Answer (score 9):

A few thoughts...

When you create the `resultsController` for the `searchController`, you can pass to it the data that you wish to search.  If you are using an `NSFetchedResultsController` in your main table, you could pass the `fetchedObjects` array.  Then in response to changes to the search text, you filter the array (you could use a predicate and `filteredArrayUsingPredicate` to create a separate array with the search results, or you could iterate through the array to build it).  The disadvantages of this route are that (unless you implement it manually) the search results will not be broken into separate sections, and the search results will not update automatically if the underlying data changes (eg. on a background thread).

I guess you could have a second `NSFetchedResultsController`: that would facilitate using sections, and could potentially permit the results to be updated automatically (using the delegate methods) if your data is being updated in the background, for example.  But I would be nervous of the complexity that it introduces.

Another option, if you opt to apply the search in situ (i.e. specify `resultsController` = nil), would be to use the search criteria to update the `NSFetchedResultsController` itself (i.e. amending the underlying predicate and reperforming the fetch).  That way your search table looks and feels exactly like the main table (including sections, if you use that) but the rows displayed obviously reduce as the search criteria become finer.  This option needs care to ensure that the FRC is properly rebuilt, and might be unacceptable performance-wise, if you have a large dataset.

Comment: Chiming in here a couple of months later, I implemented the third option above; code is much cleaner and I don't have to switch between the two `NSFetchedResultsController`s.